# Python Postgres Connections with Green Threads

Tags: python, postgresql, multithreading, psycopg2, green-threads

I am using psycopg2 and I have more than one green thread in my application. Each thread gets connections using `psycopg2.connect`. Sometimes I get the following error:

```
error: Second simultaneous read on fileno 14 detected.  Unless you really know what you're doing,
make sure that only one greenthread can read any particular socket.  Consider using a pools.Pool.
If you do know what you're doing and want to disable this error, call
eventlet.debug.hub_prevent_multiple_readers(False) - MY THREAD=<built-in method switch of
GreenThread object at 0x7fbf6aafc048>; THAT THREAD=FdListener('read', 14,
<built-in method switch of greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7fbf6aafc470>,
<built-in method throw of greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7fbf6aafc470>)
```

I don't have connection pooling configured in this project as far as I know. (`grep -ri pool .;` returns nothing.)

Does `psycopg2.connect` reuse connections in some sort of implicit connection pool?

How do I get a new connection without reusing old connections (or sockets)?

Comment: Amazing enough the `psycopg2` docs cover this [Thread and process safety](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#thread-safety) and [Support for coroutine libraries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#green-support).

Comment: I think the first link doesn't cover this as it says, "The above observations...don’t apply to ...green threads." It is not clear to me how I'm supposed to use the second link. It says "Psycopg can be used together with coroutine-based libraries and participate in cooperative multithreading." I'm not using any such libraries. I think the problem solved in the second link is increased liveliness and throughput. I don't see how it answers the question, "How do I get a new connection?". The answer by @gerpaick seems to answer the question with information not on that page.

Comment: *... I have more than one green thread in my application ...*. From here [Support for coroutine](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#green-support): *Warning
Psycopg connections are not green thread safe and can’t be used concurrently by different green threads. Trying to execute more than one command at time using one cursor per thread will result in an error (or a deadlock on versions before 2.4.2)*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for the reference. My code does not "execute more than one command at a time using one cursor...". I'm creating a new connection (calling `psycopg2.connect`) and getting a cursor from that connection for each query (on each thread) and still getting this error. It looks to me as if psycopg2 is returning already-used connections. Although I hope that's not the case, I can't tell what else could be going on.

Comment: Per the link and the quote *Psycopg connections are not green thread safe and can’t be used concurrently by different green threads.*.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My friend, I'm not using the connections concurrently. Any connection used on one thread is not used on the other thread. Thank you again for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

Psycopg2 by default resuses connection to the DB when you call *psycopg2.connect()*. many times, so if multiple green threads use the same connection at the same time, you can get this error.

To avoid this, use a connection pool, such as *SQLAlchemy* orbuilt-in *psycopg2.pool*.

Alternatively, you can create a new connection to the DB every time you need to connect to DB.

```py
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydatabase", user="myusername", password="pass", host="myhost", port="myport", connection_factory=None)
```

Note, that this can be slow and very inefficient.

Personal advice: use a connection pool.

Comment: Great, thank you! It's strange that since the default behavior uses connection pooling, you're recommending using a connection pool to avoid pooling. (Surely I have something wrong here, but that's how it looks to me!)

Comment: Because the default behavior is **not** to use pooling.  By default `con = psycopg2.connect()` creates a new connection and `con.close()` closes it, so you are incurring the cost of establishing the connection(backend process) every time you create a connection and the cost of tearing it down when closing. A pool as in the builtin [Pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html) pre-establish's connections and you then pull from the connection pool for a database operation and return to the pool when the operation is done. This takes out the overhead of creating a new backend process.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver From the error mentioned in the original question, it appears that connections are being reused between green threads without any pooling configured.

Comment: @gerpaick Based on https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/1d3a89a0bba621dc1cc9b32db6d241bd2da85ad1/lib/__init__.py#L80 it looks like `connection_factory=None` is the default, no?